# Add all the data (numbers) in a 'point' node from an xml file using php

Tags: php, xml, replace, addition

I'm using a xml file, for example:

```
     <result>
         <team>
        <name>arsenal</name>
        <games>4</games>
        <points>12</points>
        </team>
        <team>
        <name>chelsea</name>
        <games>4</games>
         <points>6</points>
        </team>
         <name>arsenal</name>
        <games>5</games>
        <points>8</points>

     </result>
```

Using php I would like to add the points (12 and 8) for arsenal.....or is there a better way rather than adding them, as I put them in the xml file I can replace arsenal and update the details, such as games and points,

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do it something like this:

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<result>
    <team>
        <name>arsenal</name>
        <games>4</games>
        <points>12</points>
    </team>
    <team>
        <name>chelsea</name>
        <games>4</games>
        <points>6</points>
    </team>
    <team>
        <name>arsenal</name>
        <games>5</games>
        <points>8</points>
    </team>
</result>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

$result = $xml->xpath('//team//name[.= "arsenal"]/..');
$points = 0;
foreach ($result as $node) {
    $points += $node->points;
}
echo "SCORE = " . $points;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, may i ask another question, i show my results on a table but i would the results to be in (highest-lowest) order, any thoughts??                                                                                                                                   ps. thanks a lot with the previous question, it helped me a lot